# Auto-importing signature from USB token to PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature

I'm wanting to buy a [third party digital signature library](http://www.digisigner.com/java_library_to_create_digital_signatures.html) and
I want to sign the PDF using client certificate.   It only works when I got the file is stored in my PC.

Since I want to sign my PDF by using the certificate stored inside a USB token, what should I do to achieve that?

Here I am having third party code and they are using a DLL file 
`C:\Windows\System32\cmP11.dll`, but is it not there in my system. What is the task of this file in the following code?

```
private static void signatureWithToken() {

  // specify document to sign
  PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument("sample.pdf");

  // specify info to find a key on the token
  String tokenLibraryFilename = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmP11.dll";  // path to token PKCS#11 library
  String tokenPin = "7777";  // token PIN
  // key alias on the token,
  // if null the first found key will be used
  String tokenKeyAlias = "Key Alias";
  SigningData signingData = SigningData.fromPkcs11Token(tokenLibraryFilename, 
      tokenKeyAlias, tokenPin);

  // list available aliases
  listAvailableAliases(signingData);

  // specify rectangle for the signature
  signingData.setFieldRectangle(new Rectangle2D.Float(300, 50, 275, 100));

  // specify reason and location
  signingData.setReason("I approve this invoice.");
  signingData.setLocation("Camden");    

  // sign document
  pdfDocument.signDocument(signingData, "sample_(signed_with_token).pdf");      
}
```

Comment: I tried my best to re-write your question, as I struggled to understand the original. Please check for any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLL file you are referring to is a [PKCS#11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF11) library, based on the code comments. PKCS#11 is a cryptographic API used to interact with tokens and [HSMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).

If you don't have that file on your system, then perhaps you are missing the PKCS#11 library for your particular USB crypto token. I would suggest you look at the manufacturer's website to see if they can share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the drivers for your crypto token. Those are generally available on the manufacturer site.  These DLL files are drivers for the crypto token.